# iOS - upload picture with ImageShack JSON API

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, imageshack

I'm trying to upload a picture to ImageShack using their [API](https://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI):

```
- (void)uploadImage2:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSData *imageToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    if (imageToUpload)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [parameters setObject:@"XXXX" forKey:@"key"];
        [parameters setObject:@"json" forKey:@"format"];
        //[parameters setObject:@"application/json" forKey:@"Content-Type"];

        AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://post.imageshack.us"]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload_api.php" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"image" fileName:@"logo.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
        }];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
             NSDictionary *jsons = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
             NSLog(@"response: %@",jsons);

         }
                                         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             if([operation.response statusCode] == 403)
             {
                 //NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
                 return;
             }
             //NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

         }];

        [operation start];
    }
}
```

As a response I get error message back with no error explanations:

```
{
    "error_code" = "upload_failed";
    "error_message" = "Upload failed";
    status = 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me with that? What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: did you tried sending `NSData` instead of `NSString` ?

Comment: yes, I did and getting the same error response

Comment: have you tried with a very small image? /to ensure its not a timeout issue

Comment: yes, I'm uploading small image 54x54 px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have managed to solve my problem. All parameters have to be set in form body, not as request values.
It looks quite simple:

```
 NSData *imageToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]);


    if (imageToUpload)
    {
        NSString *urlString = @"https://post.imageshack.us";

        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload_api.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload name:@"fileupload" fileName:@"image" mimeType:@"image/png"];
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:[@"XXXXXX" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"key"];
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:[@"json" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"format"];
        }];



        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
             NSDictionary *jsons = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
             NSLog(@"response: %@",jsons);

         }
                                         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             if([operation.response statusCode] == 403)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
                 return;
             }
             NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

         }];

        [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
    }}
```

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let us know if it works :

```
      NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadedImgView.image,1.0);//(uploadedImgView.image);
      if (imageToUpload)
      {
        NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [parameters setObject:@"MY API KEY" forKey:@"key"];
        [parameters setObject:@"json" forKey:@"format"];

        AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://post.imageshack.us"]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload_api.php" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"image" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
             NSDictionary *jsons = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
             //NSLog(@"response: %@",jsons);

         }
                                         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             if([operation.response statusCode] == 403)
             {
                 //NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
                 return;
             }
             //NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

         }];

        [operation start];
    }
```

Comment: here is a link of an question that could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931088/http-post-to-imageshack

Answer (score 1):

Uploading an Image ( Basic )

```
 Endpoint : https://post.imageshack.us/upload_api.php Parameters :
* key : The api key for your application; found in email sent after filling out our API Key Request form
* fileupload : image file
* format : json tags : a CSV list of tags to describe your picture public : A string setting your image to public or private where "yes" is public and "no" is private. Images are public by default.
```

Did you use key request and get your own key for the upload process?

```
Obtaining an API Key
To obtain an API key, please use our API Key Request form.
```

Also set format `application/json`

Comment: Yes, I use the key. It showed me an error that I should do it when I didn't use it, so I'm sure the problem is not related to the API key